# Display array of objects effieciently in React without pagination

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have an array of objects which can be accessed using - https://picsum.photos/v2/list?page=2&limit=30

The project can be accessed from - https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-vqxpcv?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FImages.js

What I want to do is to display all the 30 images on a single page for a start using React.

The issue is that the images take a lot of time to load. And the images load again when the page reloads even when the size of the images is reduced.

I would like to know if I am doing anything wrong and is there any efficient way to display the list of images?

What do we do when we have a list of 100 images instead of just 30? How do we efficiently load images in that case?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The images are *very large* (one was 4621x3070), but they're displayed *very small*. You'll want to generate *smaller images*, i.e. thumbnails, and display those instead.

Comment: @cbr I am facing similar issue of load time even when the size of the image is reduced

Comment: The API itself has an option of requesting the correct size. In your case `100px`

Comment: A simple fix would be rewrite your project with Next.js because they have an `Image` component that has optimized image loading built in. Combine that with a list virtualization like `react-window` and you should be gucci.

Comment: @Dupocas I changed the size of the image to 100px width and height. But then also, I am facing the similar issue

Comment: @J.Hesters is there any way to do it using react itself?

Comment: Maybe. Next.js is a React framework, so you'll likely not have to rewrite that much.

Comment: `react-window` or the `useInView` hook from `react-intersection-observer` are the way to go. `useInView` can be easily added to hide your image or display a placeholder unless that image is in the browser viewport.

Comment: @EdLucas Will try this as well. Thank you